# chatbot window in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create chatbot window. I found perfect version on AdminLTE page (link: https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html   ->   Direct Chat or Chat).  The main problem is that I want to have posibility to send message and have history of that to end of session. Does anyone know how to do that? I spent a lot of time by searching internet, but unfortunately I haven't found anything a bit similiar.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I really like using https://chatra.io/ on my website with ShinyApps. There is no need for you to develop anything and it's free with 1 agent.

On top of that, I use `cloudflare` as I was getting tired of referrer spam and it comes as a plugin and easy to use, note that Cloudflare offers other chat plugins also so you can choose. Below is an example of one of my apps from my website

[image]

Comment: I would like to create my own element, because I am going to use content as a control panel of my app

Comment: Hi Pork Chop it seems that my_website link is not working.